# How to make this code less repetitive? (openpyxl)

Tags: python, openpyxl

I'm a teacher and I'm making a program to facilitate myself to catalog my students' grades. This isn't so much of a problem, the deal is, I'm doing it mostly to practice programming.

```
# Name the first line
sheet['A1'] = 'Index'
sheet['B1'] = 'Name'
sheet['C1'] = 'Grade'

# Changes the style of the first line to bold
sheet['A1'].font = font_bold
sheet['B1'].font = font_bold
sheet['C1'].font = font_bold

# Widens the columns
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 10 
sheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 30
sheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = 30

# Aligns to center
sheet.cell('A1').alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
sheet.cell('B1').alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
sheet.cell('C1').alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')

# Freeze the first row
sheet.freeze_panes = 'A2'

# Index number of the lines
i = 2

--

--

# function to calculate the grade
def grade():
```

As you may notice, it is all, to some extent, repetitive. The code functions exactly as I want it to, but I would like to know some other way to make it more... succint.

It is important to remember the variables reach, because up next a function will start, and, soon after, a `While` loop.

The irrelevant parts of the code for this question have been omitted with a `---`. If they are somehow needed I'll edit them in, but to my knowledge, they are not.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Functions. `sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 10` 3 times,  can be replaced with a function that does it like `def set_width(letter, number): sheet.column_dimensions[letter].width = number` and when you want to call it, do `set_width('A', 10)`, then you can expand on that and use a loop to iterate over some sort of data structure.

Comment: `for f in ('A1', 'B1', 'C1'):` - `for c in ('A1', 'B1', 'C1'):`... how familiar are you with loops?

Comment: `sheet['A1'] = 'Index'` seems to initialize a dictionary item to `'Index'`, which is a string, and strings do not have any attributes. I wonder why `sheet['A1'].font = font_bold` doesn't cause an error?

Comment: Good idea. I'm OK with loops, it just hadn't crossed my mind to use them like this. Thank you.

Comment: @DYZ it's because it is derived from the openpyxl module versio 2.3.3 if I'm not mistaken. It's a Python module to edit excel/libreoffice spreadsheets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd take the whole thing and break it down into functions.

```
def name_column(cell, name):
    sheet[cell] = name

def style_name_column(cell, style):
    sheet[cell].font = style

def change_width(column, width):
    sheet.column_dimensions[column].width = width

def align_column(cell):
    sheet.cell(cell).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
```

then use some sort of data structure to loop over and do this stuff.

```
indexes_and_names = [['A1','Index']
                     ['B1','Name' ]
                     ['C1','Grade']]

for item in indexes_and_names:
    name_column(item[0], item[1])
```

and then repeat for the other functions, or use a bigger data structure, like Jack's dictionary.

Your code will be readable, and easily maintainable.

Comment: You attempt to avoid repeating yourself is very admirable. Please see my comment below.

Comment: This is a reasonable approach in general but I functions that only have a single line in their body should generally be avoided. In particular, the use of `sheet.cell(cell).` is significantly more confusing than `sheet[cell]`

Comment: Agreed, i just took what he had and put it into functions. This can be turned into a single function with 4 lines a piece, but then your input data structure gets more complex. But this is to convey the general idea, that functions make your code less complex and repetative.

Answer (score 2):

## Objects and DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) Principle

In general, whenever you have some parallel arrays of the same length that keep some related attribute, it is a good indication that you can combine those attributes and make an object out of them.
For your case, I see that suggest to define an object Sheet with the following attributes:

- title
- font
- column_dimensions
- cell
- ...

Comment: This is the truest answer here. If OP knows how to create classes, then this is the direction OP should go.

Comment: Thank you. I'm still studying my way through OOP. Will change the code when I feel able.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good start:

```
items = [
  {"sheet": "A1", "column": "A", "column_width": 10, "title": "Index"},
  {"sheet": "B1", "column": "B", "column_width": 30, "title": "Name"},
  {"sheet": "C1", "column": "C", "column_width": 30} "title": "Grade"},
]

for item in items:
    sheet[item["sheet"]] = item["title"]
    sheet[item["sheet"]].font = font_bold # always bold
    sheet.column_dimensions[item["column"]] = item["column_width"] # shared value
    sheet.cell(item["sheet"]).alignment = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center') # shared value
```

Comment: Damn, man. That's great. Never thought of using dictionaries like that. You've just opened a world of possibilities for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

openpyxl provides all the necessary functions to do this quickly and easily. The best way to do this is to use [named styles](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styles.html#named-styles). You can create a single style for the header cells and apply it using a loop.

Create the first row:

`ws.append(['Index', 'Name', 'Grade'])`

Create the relevant style:

`header = NamedStyle(…)`

Apply the style to the first row:

```
for cell in ws[1]:
    cell.style = header
```